# Как установить фон кнопки по полученному id или имени?

Tags: android, button, background

В активити много кнопок: button1, button2 ... button30 c id buttonCard1, buttonCard2 и т.д.
Есть база SQL на 30 позиций, то есть для каждой кнопки заведено значение 1,2 или 3.
Задача такая: через цикл for прогнать по порядку эти значения из базы и для тех кнопок которым задано значение 1 установить background. Получаю строковое значение id, но не пойму как на него применить фон.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 30; i++){
        userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DbDataHelper.TABLE + " where " +
                DbDataHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(i)});
        color = userCursor.getInt(3);
        if(color == 1){
            String id = "R.id.buttonCard" + i; //На полученный id нужно применить background
            ???(Integer.valueOf(id)).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButton1));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что строка с именем не может быть напрямую преобразована в ID ресурса. Код может быть примерно таким (для кода в активити, которая имеет метод findViewById()):

```
if(color == 1){
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("buttonCard" + i, "id", getPackageName());
       Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id);
       btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButton1));

    }
```